# Outlook VSTO addin not calling linux APIs, but same code running in console app

Tags: c#, ubuntu, nginx, vsto, fastapi

I have created a Outlook VSTO addin using C#. This addin is supposed to call some APIs which are running on my company server. The APIs are hosted on Ubuntu, as fastapi behing nginx.
Whenever I try to call api from VSTO C# using httpClient , error i get is - `InnerException` - `Unable to connect to the remote server`   .. and `SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond`.

However, same code I copied in windows form and also in separate console app. At both places same API is working fine and also working from Postman. Also same VSTO c# code is able to call other webservices like microsoft Graph API etc. Only my company webservice hosted by me on ubuntu on nginx is not being called.

As a temporary workaround, I hosted a fastapi uvicorn API on my localhost windows laptop, and VSTO was successfully calling it. This localhost api in turn is calling that mycompany hosted api.

I could not understand why only VSTO code is not calling that server hosted api. Any clues?

Following code modifications are also done, but still specific APIs are failing:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
 ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
 ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
 ServicePointManager.UseNagleAlgorithm = false;


 var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler
 {
     AllowAutoRedirect = true // Enable automatic redirection
 };

 using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler))
```

**One interesting thing happened - somehow i installed fiddler. When fiddler is running the API call works , but when fiddler is not running then API call does not work.**

**Also, code is able to call another api hosted in windows by some other application in same company. Seems it is issue related to api hosted by Ubuntu. I also tried disabling nginx and just running flask. Not sure why VSTO is not liking ubuntu**
**I tried `sudo nc -l -p 443 -k -v -s myserverip` ... and checked telnet from laptop , the request was printed, but from VSTO it was not printed....**

Comment: Does the error message actually say "**web**service did not respond..."? maybe it's saying just "service"? I.e. windows service?

Comment: Exact message is - InnerException - Unable to connect to the remote server   .. and SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond  .... I have shown the code as well above

Comment: Are console application and VSTO add-in target the same version of the .NET framework?

Comment: Yes.. same version 4.7 .. Also tried with windows form application same .net version and also tried with .net core application with framework 6.. Everywhere same code is working except from outlook VSTO addin

Comment: Can you see the outgoing request, Using Fiddler for example? i.e. does the exception occur on sending or on receiving the response? Other than that, are you sure you are actually setting SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 (i.e. the code you showed is actually executing in the VSTO plugin?

Comment: due to security in office laptop, i can not install fiddler or wireshark.. And the code I shown above is not executing in VSTO..i added TLS etc as per internet suggestions, but still not working.. The api on nginx is on TLS1.2 though

Comment: One interesting thing happened - somehow i installed fiddler. When fiddler is running the API call works , but when fiddler is not running then API call does not work.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of this issue then: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28861124/vsto-outlook-plugin-httpclient-postasync-fails-without-fiddler The problem there is TLS 1.2 is not enabled, as far as I understand. I would double-check that, to make sure the code that enables TLS 1.2 is actually called and works. Note - you can enable TLS 1.2 also via registry setting: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/configmgr/core/plan-design/security/enable-tls-1-2-client. Also, the your add-in seem to be running 4.5 version framework not 4.7

Comment: Alternatively, you can enable TLS 1.1 on your unix server - should also start working.

Comment: I have enabled all ssl versions in nginx .. still api is not callable.. even the hit is not coming in nginx access and error log.. Also, code is able to call another api hosted in windows by some other application in same company. Seems it is issue related to api hosted by nginx

Comment: I also tried disabling nginx and just running flask. Not sure why VSTO is not liking ubuntu

Comment: I don't think it's linux, I think it's still TLS 1.2 disabled in VSTO by default (that's the most common issue). Have you checked your have it enabled? You can use openssl tool to test what is actually enabled/disabled, I'd try that first. https://serverfault.com/questions/106482/how-can-i-see-what-version-of-ssl-a-web-server-is-currently-using

Comment: I had printed the ssprotocols in ServicePointManager.. below are the printed outputs , which means these are enabled at VSTO httpClient - Ssl3
Tls
Tls11
Tls12

Comment: Have you tried to change the registry key? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33761919/tls-1-2-in-net-framework-4-0

Comment: I started jupyterhub as root on ubuntu, and opened it in my laptop browser as http://unixip:443 (note- http, 444), it worked. But same did not work from VSTO ... Not able to figure out if it is unix problme, or it is some specific restrictions on VSTO

Comment: So have you tried to modify the registry key as in the answer in the linked question? This will enable 1.2 without programmatic settings.

Comment: regedit is disabled by my company.. but i tried `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)768 | (SecurityProtocolType)3072;` 
This did not work

Comment: But if this is dotnet problem, then same code should not work from windows form or console application..

Comment: This is programmatic. I just wanted to check if you can enable it without code.

Comment: Additionally, not sure why only calls to Linux servers is blocked. and not the windows server api or even public hosted api !

Comment: I tried  sudo nc -l -p 443 -k -v -s myserverip  ... and checked telnet from laptop , the request was printed, but from VSTO it was not printed....

Comment: you need to check with specific TLS protocol, not generic SSL. i.e. TLS 1.2. This is a recent security requirement change (done in a past few years) that affected many users. 1.1 and below are not considered secure enough, and therefore were disabled by most systems by default by various security patches.

Comment: Please refer to the link above how to check what version of TLS your server suggests using openssl.

Comment: @SandeepBhutani have you tried explicitely set the TLS Version: `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;` before making the API call

Comment: Hi @James: Yes,,, as you can see the code above in the post, I have done the suggestion already before http call